# Location of historical 'last' command data (wtmp)

Tags: terminal, command-line, login

I can run

```
last myusername
```

and it will show all login information

> myusername  console                   Fri Feb  5 09:06   still logged in

> myusername  console                   Thu Feb  4 17:55 - 18:45  (00:50)

> wtmp begins Thu Feb  4 17:50

However, it doesn't show anything older than that. I found that wtmp is saved in /var/log/asl/ but I can't find the exact place the historical login information is saved in. Where would I find the 'last' login info that is older than what is shown in the current 'last' command output?